I am working with react app and I am creating a note and comment. For the comment, I want to had a remove button
export default function Comment({ index, onRemoveComment, children }) {
    
    function removeComment() {
        // console.log(" ... removeComment calls onRemoveComment ...");

        onRemoveComment(index);
    } 
//

    return (
        <div className="comment">
                <p>{children}
                <span>
                    <button onClick={removeComment} id="removeComment">
                        Remove</button> 
                </span>
                
                </p>        
        </div>
    )
}

I tried changing where I placed id for the remove comment, but I am not sure where to add the id of comment.
